# How to disable a redis instance or make it readonly?

Tags: redis

I have configured Redis in non-cluster mode, and for specific hours of the day want to disable it or make it readonly (any one would do). Found that in cluster mode, *READWRITE* command can be used to disable queries to slave node if earlier that was enabled using *READONLY*. Tried *CLIENT PAUSE* command but  that didn't work, seems even that is meant for cluster mode.

Comment: what's your redis version?

Comment: @MallowFox It's 3.0.5